# Curl hidden field with randomly generated value

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to access the value of a hidden field in a form which i'm trying to log into using curl. I realise this is childs play with curl **but** the headache here is that i have to use the same curling to:
(1) Get that unique randomly generated session value
(2) Log into the form

The problem is (2) requires (1) in order to proceed. Can i do both in one curl?

Comment: The site owner undoubtedly NOT welcome such an intrusion. Why to break in anyway? Why to make our internet even worst?

Comment: if you have a valid reason for needing to do this, I _strongly_ suggest that you update your question to explain it. If this question becomes a disruption to the Stack Overflow community, I will close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is, you can't. You'll have to fetch the form, extract the hidden serial and then make another cURL request with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You will probably need to first grab the page, then parse it for the hidden field (I would suggest something like [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) but a regex might work too). Once you have that, you can submit the form in the way that you want.

Comment: I've tried your methods, but unfortunately the problem with this is that, the session value discovered by one curl would have expired by the time the 2nd curl attempts to use it.

Comment: The session value expires in under a second? That's how long it should take to grab the first page, parse it, extract the session ID and make a second request. If that's the case then the form that it's hidden is completely useless since *nothing* can possibly use it